# Access element attribute from request

Tags: html

Is there a way to access an elements attributes from a request?

I am receiving a request and I want to access the 'id' attribute of the input tag.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to get the value of the attribute or you also want to modify it? 'coz if you want to change it let say, it's not gonna work, you need some workarounds for that. What server side script are you using?

Comment: No I don't need to modify it. Im using java with spring mvc stuff to get the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, use JavaScript to include element attributes as request data (like querystring or post data) in your request.

```
<form method="post" action="page.jsp" onsubmit="setDataFirst();">
    <input id="container" name="container" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input id="YourElement" class="AttributeClassValue" name="YourElement" type="text" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    //This function will execute before the form will be submitted...
    function setDataFirst()
    {
        //Set the value of container to the attribute you want to send to server...
        document.getElementById('container').value = 'YourElementClass=' + document.getElementById('YourElement').attributes('class');
        //After the function execution, the form will be submitted...
    }
</script>


Now in your server you can get the value of POST data `container` which is `YourElementClass=AttributeClassValue`
```

Comment: what javascript line would I use to add  it as an attribute to a request? I am not sure how I can modify the request on the html page.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the id attribute is really for CSS styling and Javascript manipulation.

It sounds like you need the id attribute value to be passed back to the server.
Whether you are using a POST or GET method, you'll have to use Javascript to manipulate the value of the input field to add the value of the id of the input element to the value of the input element itself.

e.g suppose

```
`<input type="..." id="fred"  ...`
```

and the value, on form submission, is 'test'  you'll need to write a Javascript function that manipulates the value to 'fred.test'

However, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-attributes shows the name attribute still in use.  If you use

`<input type="..." id="fred" name="fred" ...`

then you should receive the name/value pair as fred=test, serverside.